# Polynomials and Commutativity

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let $f(x)=2013x+1$. Suppose $g(x), h(x)$ are polynomials with real coefficients such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ and $f(h(x))=h(f(x))$. Prove that $g(h(x))=h(g(x))$.

I tried to look at the coefficients of both sides but it didn't quite help. We also have $ghf=gfh=fgh$ and $hgf=hfg=fhg$ (multiplication meaning composition here) but I couldn't see how it helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: *g,h* are each either the inverse of *f* (which we can calculate if needed), or the identity, right?

Answer (score 4):

If $g$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ with leading coefficient $a$, i.e.
$g(x) = a x^m + \ldots$ where $\ldots$ consists of terms of lower order, and $m \ge 1$ then $f(g(x)) = 2013 a x^m + \ldots$ while $g(f(x)) = 2013^m a x^m + \ldots$, so $f(g(x)) - g(f(x)) = (2013 - 2013^m) a x^m + \ldots$.
Thus $f(g(x)) - g(f(x))$ can't be $0$ unless $m \le 1$.  If we try a polynomial $g(x) = a x + b$ of degree $\le 1$, we find that in order to 
get $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$ we need $a = 2012 b + 1$.  Thus the only polynomials that commute with $f$ are $g(x) = (2012 b + 1) x + b$.  It's easy to check that these commute with each other.